# Find index of object in javascript using its property name

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, javascript-objects

I want to find Index of javascript array of objects using objects property name. My code is :-

```
const checkbox = [{'mumbai': true},{'bangalore': true},{'chennai': true},{'kolkata': true}];
```

How can i find index of chennai? Can i acheive using lodash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```js
const checkbox = [
  {'mumbai': true},
  {'bangalore': true},
  {'chennai': true},
  {'kolkata': true}
];

const finder = (arr, key) => arr.findIndex(o => key in o);

console.log(finder(checkbox, 'chennai'));
console.log(finder(checkbox, 'kolkata'));
console.log(finder(checkbox, 'delhi'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
checkbox.map((v,i) => Object.keys(v).indexOf("chennai") !== -1 ? i : -1).filter(v => v !== -1)[0]
```

Will give you the index of "chennai", replace it with any other key to get a different index.

What this does is:

- Map the array to an array indicating only indices which contain objects with the wanted key
- Filter only the indices which you want
- Get the first one (you can use the rest as well if there are multiple entries matching your search)

This works in every browser since it only uses .map() , Object.keys() and .filter()